# SQL Stored Procedure LIKE

Tags: sql

This is a simple question and I can't seem to think of a solution.

I have this defined in my stored procedure:

```
@communityDesc varchar(255) = NULL
```

@communityDesc is "aaa,bbb,ccc"

and in my actual query I am trying to use `IN`

```
WHERE AREA IN (@communityDesc)
```

but this will not work because my commas are inside the string instead of like this "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"

So my question is, is there anything I can do to @communityDesc so it will work with my IN statement, like reformat the string?

Comment: Are you executing this just in SQL, or are you trying to duplicate what [table valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) were added to accomplish?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: **[Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at first you most create a function to split string some thing like this code

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

then you can use this function is your query like this

```
WHERE AREA IN (dbo.splitstring(@communityDesc))
```

Comment: Is this an Inline Table-valued Function, Multi-statement Table-valued Function or Scalar-valued Function?

Comment: I created the function, but got this error `'splitstring' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Answer (score 5):

This article could help you by your problem:

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

In this article Aaron Bertrand is writing about your problem.
It's really long and very detailed.

One Way would be this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

With this function you only call:

```
WHERE AREA IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@communityDesc, N','))
```

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to use this variable is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM something
WHERE ',' + @communityDesc + ',' Like '%,' + AREA + ',%'
```

this is for tsql, for oracle use `||` to concatenate strings

Answer (score 3):

`In` only works with sets of values, not with characters in a string. To answer your question technically, the only way you could do this is to create a set of values representing the three values 'aaa', 'bbb' & 'ccc' and then put those three values into a table (a Temp Table or table variable (in SQL Server), and then perform IN against that set of values (against the table:

```
declare @Vals table (value varchar(20))
insert @vals(Value) Values('aaa')
insert @vals(Value) Values('bbb')
insert @vals(Value) Values('ccc')

select * from SomeOtherTable 
Where SomeColumn IN (Select value from @vals)
```

To create the set you would need to create an empty temp table or table variable to hold this set of values, parse the comma delimited string into individual values, and enter those individual values into the temp table or table variable.

although you don't say, if you are using SQL Server, the following is a SQL Server User Defined function (UDF) that will parse a delimited string and return a table with one row for each delimted value:

if you create the UDF, then you would use it as follows:

```
select * from SomeOtherTable 
Where SomeColumn IN 
        (Select sVal from
          dbo.ParseSTring(@communityDesc, ','))
```

---

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ParseString]    
    Script Date:      4/8/2016 1:53:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseString] (@S Text, @delim VarChar(5))
Returns @tOut Table 
(ValNum Integer Identity Primary Key, 
 sVal VarChar(8000))
As
Begin 
Declare @dLLen TinyInt  -- Length of delimiter
Declare @sWin  VarChar(8000)-- Will Contain Window into text string
Declare @wLen  Integer  -- Length of Window
Declare @wLast TinyInt  -- Boolean to indicate processing Last Window
Declare @wPos  Integer  -- Start Position of Window within Text String
Declare @sVal  VarChar(8000)-- String Data to insert into output Table
Declare @BtchSiz Integer    -- Maximum Size of Window
Set @BtchSiz = 7900 -- (Reset to smaller values to test routine)
Declare @dPos Integer   -- Position within Window of next Delimiter
Declare @Strt Integer   -- Start Position of each data value in Window
-- --------------------------------------------------------------

-- ---------------------------
If @delim is Null Set @delim = '|'
If DataLength(@S) = 0 Or
    Substring(@S, 1, @BtchSiz) = @delim Return
-- ---------------------------
Select @dLLen = Len(@delim),
    @Strt = 1, @wPos = 1,
    @sWin = Substring(@S, 1, @BtchSiz)
Select @wLen = Len(@sWin),
      @wLast = Case When Len(@sWin) = @BtchSiz
                Then 0 Else 1 End,
      @dPos = CharIndex(@delim, @sWin, @Strt)
-- ----------------------------
While @Strt <= @wLen
  Begin
    If @dPos = 0 Begin    -- No More delimiters in window
        If @wLast = 1 Set @dPos = @wLen + 1 
        Else Begin
            Set @wPos = @wPos + @Strt - 1
            Set @sWin = Substring(@S, @wPos, @BtchSiz)
                -- -------------------------------------
            Select @wLen = Len(@sWin), @Strt = 1,
            @wLast = Case When Len(@sWin) = @BtchSiz
                Then 0 Else 1 End, 
                                      @dPos = CharIndex(@delim, @sWin, 1)
            If @dPos = 0 Set @dPos = @wLen + 1 
            End
        End
        -- -------------------------------
    Set @sVal = LTrim(Substring(@sWin, @Strt, @dPos - @Strt))
    Insert @tOut (sVal) Values (@sVal)
    -- -------------------------------
    -- Move @Strt to char after last delimiter
    Set @Strt = @dPos + @dLLen 
    Set @dPos = CharIndex(@delim, @sWin, @Strt)
    End
Return
 End
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by splitting your string using a split function provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string). The function returns a table having a single column which holds your tokens (i.e. 'aaa', 'bbb' ...).

Your query should look like this:

```
-- get the splits
SELECT Name INTO #someTemp
FROM dbo.splitstring(@communityDesc)

-- get data where area in within description
SELECT 1
FROM yourTable T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #someTemp tmp WHERE T.Area = tmp.Name)
```

Comment: I get two errors, Invalid Column name 'Name' and Invalid object name 'dbo.splitstring'

Comment: Run `dbo.splitstring` function from provided link first to have your function in the database.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach is to use CHARINDEX().   However, using a function in a WHERE clause will slow down the performance.

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(','+area+',',','+@CommunityDec+',')> 0
```

If you area field is always 3 letters, you can simplify this.

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(area,@CommunityDec)> 0
```

This is a quick solution, but also a stop gap.   A better solution is to change the string lookup approach to build a table with one row per search criteria and using a JOIN or sub query.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split this csv using XML and use this to filter in your query. No need to use a User defined function or @Table_Valiable or #Temp_Table here.

```
DECLARE @xml as xml,@communityDesc varchar(255) = 'aaa,bbb,ccc'

SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@communityDesc,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)

SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE AREA IN (
    SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
)
```

If you required this split values in further process, then you can Insert this to a #table_Variable or #Temp_Table and use them.

Comment: If you required this split values in further process, then only you can INsert this to a #table_Variable or #Temp_Table and use them, Sample below,

INSERT INTO @Table_variable
SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)

SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE AREA IN (SELECT Col1 from @Table_variable)