# Select split values with their matching ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a following table:

```
id (int)  | val (varchar)
------------------------------------
1         | 4234,15345,1324,1534,1512
2         | 215,22867,2456,24756,2423
3         | 3123,3452,3356,3478,3995
```

Also, I have a function fnSplitString (string varchar(max), deliminator char(1)), which works like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM fnSplitString ((SELECT val FROM idval WHERE id = 1),',')
```

produces output:

```
    val (varchar)
------------
    4234
    15345
    1324
    1534
    1512
```

My goal is to produce a table like this:

```
id (int)  val (varchar)
    ------------
 1       4234
 1       15345
 1       1324
 1       1534
 1       1512
 2       215
 2       22867
 2       2456
 ...
```

I know how to achieve it using a cursor and inserting into a temporary table. I am just curious if this could be done without a cursor though? Let's assume I don't want to modify the fnSplitString function at first. So far I've come up with one part of the query:

```
SELECT id, spl.val 
FROM idval JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM fnSplitString ((SELECT val FROM idval WHERE id = 1),',')) spl 
ON 1=1 
WHERE id = 1
```

Which leaves me with the result table only for rows with id = 1.

Comment: Don't store data like comma separated items (in a column), it will only cause you lots of problems. Normalize! One value/row is the SQL way!

Comment: Yep, no choice when importing data from our clients. Thanks for your advice anyway ;]

Comment: I know what you mean, having to clean up after others...

Comment: You can even split a CSV without using a UDF -fnSplitString . http://stackoverflow.com/a/36686492/5366015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM idval i
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(i.val, ',') f
```

Comment: I knew it'll be simple but not that much ;] I just need to get rid of the duplicate val column here. Thanks!